# Combination with restriction

Tags: combinatorics

The problem I am trying to solve is the kinds as below.
$l,m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\leq m\leq l$ (fixed numbers)
$S$: a set of size $l$
$H_i$:sets of subsets of $S$ of size $m$
$G=\{H_{i_1},H_{i_2},\cdots\}$ s.t. for any $p\neq q$ any subsets of $H_{i_p}$ and $H_{i_q}$ of size $n$ are different.
My question is what is the maximum size of the set $G$ satisfying above condition.
If $m=n$, life is easy. Its just $ _lC_{n}$.
However if you have $m<n$, it seems rather complicated.
Suppose I have a set of size 100, say $S=\{1,2,\cdots,100\}$ and let $m=5$, $n=4$. I want to find the largest size of  $G=\{ \{1,2,3,4,5\},\{1,2,3,6,7\},\{1,2,3,8,9\},\cdots\}$, but I am not sure how it can be solved easily.
Is there any known theorem for such problems

Comment: @talegari Thanks for your insightful comment. I will try and think of a case violating above equality

Comment: I found that the bound is achieved if the steiner system $(n,m,l)$ exists. I have deleted my comment and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $|G|\binom{m}{n}\le \binom{l}{n}$ as we can associate $\binom{m}{n}$ subsets (of size n) with each $H_i$. This gives the upper bound $$|G|\le \frac{\binom{l}{n}}{\binom{m}{n}}$$
This upper bound is achieved only if a steiner system $(n,m,l)$ exists.